# How to execute sudo NOPASSWD command on other server via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo

I have read all the post related to the issue. But If you can see mine as well and give suggestion.

I am trying to do passwordless SSH and run a script on remote server. But Sudo access ask for Password. Please suggest. It ran fine for local path. But any command or script require root access fails.

Below is the Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x
# This Script will search for mib files on Current Server and other Server
# to load mib on current Server.

if [ -f /home/shuksand/Script/MibSearch.conf ]
then
        . /home/shuksand/Script/MibSearch.conf
else
        echo "Failed to find config file. Hence Existing!!!!"
fi

# Check alll MIBS on Server


while read line
do
        ServerName=$line
        echo $line
        scp  /home/shuksand/Input/Mib.txt $ServerName:
        cat /home/shuksand/Input/Mib.txt | while read DATA
        do
                echo $DATA
                ssh -t -t shuksand@${ServerName} 'sudo su - root /bin/sh /home/shuksand/Mib.sh $DATA'
        done
done < /home/shuksand/Input/ServerList.txt
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is typically caused by the sudoers file.  One thing to try is to make a script just run sh, and then run the sudo command from that sh prompt, and see if a password is needed.

Note that sudo tends to remember if you recently authenticated the password from the same login.  So if sudo considers you to be sufficiently authenticated once (perhaps you typed a password), and then you make a change to /etc/sudoers, and then you try to sudo again, you could easily be misled because sudo might not prompt you, because sudo might remember that you passed the test less than 5 minutes ago.  This is set by the "timeout" value in /etc/sudoers (man sudoers).

> sudo su - root /bin/sh /home/shuksand/Mib.sh $DATA

looks like it is probably, rather unnecessarily, convoluted.  I've sometimes seen sudo work, and su fail, or vice versa.  That command requires both to work.  On many systems,

> sudo -i ~shuksand/Mib.sh $DATA

will probably do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is edit your /etc/sudoers file. Add something like this:

```
<your username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

You can find more information here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

May I suggest that you fix the formatting for your question? Most of what you write (the script) is not really relevant to your question.

Edit: If you have correctly set the Mib.sh file to be executable and include the !#/bin/sh line in the start of the file then all you need to run is 'sudo su - /home/shuksand/Mib.sh $DATA' ("root" is implied/default when doing su)